# Mockito stubbing with matchers

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, stubbing

I'm trying to stub a method of a spy in my test like

```
AnotherClass anotherClass = mock(AnotherClass.class);
doReturn(any(MyClass.class)).when(mySpy).myMethod(anotherClass);
```

So mockito throws an InvalidUseOfMatchersException

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced argument matcher detected here:

-> at mypackage.MyTest.testMyMethod(MyTest.java:50)
```

Can anybody explain what's wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, why would you want to return a matcher? Does your non-test code use mockito?

Comment: Of course my non test code doesn't use mockito. I want just to stub method which returns instance of MyClass, but I don't want to create this instance.

Comment: Ok, I don't want to create it manualy. It doesn't mean for me what to return in this case, I just want to stub a method.

Comment: Well you have to return SOMETHING. If you really don't care what to return, return null. If you DO care and want some methods of the returned object to work - you have to specify how they work. By either creating an instance or mocking.

Comment: Can you update your example to show what happens in the MyTest.testMyMethod method?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you understand the use of `doReturn`. You shouldn't be trying to match on what's being returned. What your doing it telling Mockito what to return. see below

```
AnotherClass anotherClass = mock(AnotherClass.class);
doReturn(new MyClass()).when(mySpy).myMethod(anotherClass);
```